# Terminal command no longer working after upgrading macOS to Ventura

Tags: terminal, finder, ventura

I have a simple command to open a new instance of the downloads folder in the Finder, but it does not work under macOS Ventura:

```
open -n ~/Downloads
```

which returns

```
The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000032c54d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}
user@MacBook-Air-Name ~ %
```

I have not changed the folder structure at all. So, I'm unsure what the cause is.

Comment: Does it only happen with the Downloads folder or also with others? Does it work if you do `mkdir ~/ad-test; open -n ~/ad-test`?

Comment: Interesting. I get this also, but only with the `-n` option (to open a new instance of Finder, which is already running ofc... ). Also occurs with a newly created folder as per @nohillside M1 MBP, Ventura (13.0). Suggest to OP this is as straightforward as opening a bug with Apple. I also tried with other app, eg opening Numbers sheets. works fine with them, so problem may be restricted to Finder.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what fixed it, but I had the same problem with some scripts I was running through npm inside phpstorm.
(calling the same command directly in terminal worked though.)
But I ran `xcode-select --install`, and restarted my applications, and now it seems to work?

If someone can reproduce, please place this as an answer.

Comment: @CasperdeGroot Unfortunately that didn't work for me with Finder. Did the `--install` and rebooted. Same issue as per OP and my experience.

Comment: @CasperdeGroot even xcode-select command fails even when xcode is installed

Comment: Is there a reason you want two intances of the Finder open at the same time? Why not simple "open ~/Downloads" to open an additional window?

Answer (score 4):

`open -n` opens a new instance of the same application. You would then have to "Finder" at the same time.

On Monterey, it was not generating an error but was not opening a second instance (it seems that the option was ignored).

On Ventura is giving an error (since having two Finders is most likely not supported).

If you omit the `-n` option, you will get an additional Finder window with the specified folder

Comment: Just tested... in Ventura this does NOT give an additional window at the specified folder.  It will simply put focus on that Finder window when it's already open.  I believe this whole post is about opening an *additional* Finder, even when there is already a Finder window pointing at the same folder....